# When to update subscription end date in database from the stripe events

Tags: stripe-payments, .net-core-2.0

I have webhook endpoints where all the events occur.But I am confused when to update the subscription date in database when I have auto renewal payment.What does the customer.subscription.updated event have in its object? Is it possible with this only or any other event to be used

Comment: `What does the customer.subscription.updated event have in its object` A [subscription object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object). I'd highly recommend just testing this yourself so you can play around with the objects that are returned — write some test code to create a subscription, set `TrialEnd = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5)`, so that when the trial ends it simulates a new billing period and you will receive webhook events you can look at.